# Proving the rectangle theorem using Green's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, contour-integration, greens-theorem

**Question 1**

I want to prove that given $ f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C} $ and rectangle $ R $ with boundary $\gamma $ anti-clockwise, the line integral over $ f $ would be $ 0 $.

I'm pretty sure with my way but I cannot find my mistake. Here's what I have tried:

Assume that $ f\left(x,y\right)=\left(u\left(x,y\right),v\left(x,y\right)\right) $ (we will recognize $\mathbb{C} $ with $\mathbb{R}^2$, and assume $ \gamma\left(t\right)=\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right),\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace a\leq t\leq b $

Then,by definition we have:

$$ \intop_{\gamma}fdz=\intop_{a}^{b}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\cdot\dot{\gamma}\left(t\right)dt $$

$$ =\intop_{a}^{b}\left[\left(u\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right),v\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right)\right)\right]\cdot\left[\left(\dot{x}\left(t\right),\dot{y}\left(t\right)\right)\right]dt $$

$$ =\intop_{a}^{b}\left[u\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right)\dot{x}\left(t\right)+v\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right)\dot{y}\left(t\right)\right]dt $$

$$ =\intop_{\gamma}u\left(x,y\right)dx+v\left(x,y\right)dy\underset{\text{Green's Theorem}}{=}\intop_{R}\left(v_{x}-u_{y}\right)dxdy $$

I used Gree'ns theorem as it stated in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)

What I actually need in those parenthesis is $ \left(u_{x}-v_{y}\right) $ so I can use Cauchy-Riemann equations and claim that the integrand is $0$, but seems like I was wrong somewhere

Any help and clarifications would be very helpful and I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do we know about $f$.  For example, if $f$ is holomorphic, then yes, you can show that the integral around the rectangle is zero.  Otherwise, usually $\int_\text{rectangle} f(z)\, dz \ne 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We regard $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$. Your first one is just not the definition of contour integration. It gives you a real number, so is definitely not correct. Your second one is correct. The first  integral you computed is (with $f = u + iv$)
$$\int_{\partial R}u\,dx + v\,dy,$$
while the definition of the contour integral is
$$\int_{\partial R}f\,dz := \int_{\partial R}f(dx + i\,dy) = \int_{\partial R}f\,dx + if\,dy.$$
Green's theorem applies to functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$ too (this follows easily from the real version of Green's theorem), so applying Green's theorem to $(f, if)$ gives
$$\int_{\partial R}f\,dx + if\,dy = \int_{R}(if_x - f_y)\,d(x, y).$$
If $f$ is holomorphic, then $if_x - f_y = 0$, which yields your result.

Edit: The contour integral is defined as the line integral of the vector field $(f, if)$, a complex valued vector field. The integral of such a vector field is defined componentwise. That means it is really two real integrals. We can expand to see them
\begin{align}
f\,dz &= (u + iv)\,(dx + i\,dy) \\
&= u\,dx - v\,dy + i(u\,dy + v\,dx). \\
\end{align}
So
$$\int_{\partial R}f\,dz = \int_{\partial R}(u\,dx - v\,dy) + i\int_{\partial R}(v\,dx + u\,dy).$$

Comment: Can you write the correct definition of the contour integral without involving $\mathbb{C} $? (assuming $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2 $. I want to know how could I solve it in the first way

Comment: @FreeZe The contour integral is a complex number (i.e. a pair of real numbers). I expanded it to show what those two real numbers are.